# VSO - 2 factor authentication

Tags: azure-devops

Can I setup 2 factor authentication for users using LiveID? It seems like only Azure Active Directory is possible and just wondering if I've missed out anything.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each user needs to configure two factor themselves. Send them to http://account.live.com.